# Unable to POST to custom user registration field Services 3.0 Drupal

Tags: json, rest, drupal-7

When trying to post to my custom zip code field on user registration form it get the following:

**post data to endpoint/user/register.json**

```
{
"name":"testuser123",
"pass":"testuser123",
"mail":"testuser123@gmail.com",
"field_zip_code":{
"und": {
"0": {
"postal": {
"value":"11209"}
}
}
}
}
```

**response:**

```
{
"form_errors": {
"field_zip_code][und][0][postal": "Postal Code field is required."
}
}
```

If make the zip code field not required - the post is successful (user is created) but zip is not entered. Seems like the field is missing the start and end brackets - not sure if that is relevant.

See screenshot for the form data that i believe i matched with the post:
http://puu.sh/rRU34/1fe628599c.png

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  "field_zip_code":{"und": [{"postal": "11111"}]}
```

was the correct format.